# Сайт на DLE. Логи. Непонятный посетитель.

Tags: apache, php, логирование, dle

Добрый вечер. Имеется сайт на DLE. Последнее время с разных ip адресов стали поступать вот такие запросы на несуществующую страницу. Никто с таким не сталкивался? Что за посетительбот это может быть?

```
178.154.239.31 - - [09/Apr/2012:14:23:36 +0400] "GET /0164572744c2.htm HTTP/1.0" 404 1734
178.154.239.31 - - [09/Apr/2012:14:23:36 +0400] "GET /0164572744c2.htm HTTP/1.0" 404 1734
178.154.239.31 - - [09/Apr/2012:14:23:36 +0400] "GET /0164572744c2.htm HTTP/1.0" 404 1734
178.154.239.31 - - [09/Apr/2012:14:23:36 +0400] "GET /0164572744c2.htm HTTP/1.0" 404 1734
178.154.239.31 - - [09/Apr/2012:14:23:36 +0400] "GET /0164572744c2.html HTTP/1.0" 404 14606
178.154.239.31 - - [09/Apr/2012:14:23:36 +0400] "GET /0164572744c2.html HTTP/1.0" 404 14606
178.154.239.31 - - [09/Apr/2012:14:23:36 +0400] "GET /0164572744c2.html HTTP/1.0" 404 14606
178.154.239.31 - - [09/Apr/2012:14:23:36 +0400] "GET /0164572744c2.html HTTP/1.0" 404 14606
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Это один из сервисов яндекса, скорее всего поисковый бот.

```
route:          178.154.128.0/17
descr:          Yandex network
```

Answer (score 0):

Есть мнение что это попытка DDos-a, хоть и с одного компьютера, может сбой в ботнете мало ли что, заблокируйте его IP-адрес на всякий пожарный.